# Inherit bool field in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, boolean

I'm very new to C++. I'm created an interface called `shape.h` and I have two classes that I want them to inherit from it: `plane.cpp` and `sphere.cpp` (both have their own `.h` files. I don't know if it's relevant but I thought it's worth mentioning).
One of the fields of `shape.h` is: `bool isRound` and I want `sphere.cpp` constructor to change it to `true` and `plane.cpp` constructor to change it to `false`. That's how I did it in sphere:

```
sphere::sphere(Vector3f Center, float Radius, Vector3f Ka, Vector3f Kd, Vector3f Ks, float Shininess) : shape(Ka, Kd, Ks, Shininess){
    this->ka = Ka;
    this->kd = Kd;
    this->ks = Ks;
    this->radius = Radius;
    this->center = Center;
    this->shininess = Shininess;
    this->isRound = true;
}
```

and in plane:

```
plane::plane(Vector3f Ka, Vector3f Kd, Vector3f Ks, Vector3f Normal, Vector3f Point, float shininess) : shape(Ka, Kd, Ks, shininess){
this->shininess = shininess;
this->ka = Ka;
this->kd = Kd;
this->ks = Ks;
this->normal = Normal;
this->point = Point;
this->isRound = false;
```

}

This is how my `shape.h` looks like:

```
class shape
{
protected:
    Vector3f color;
public:
    Vector3f ka;
    Vector3f kd;
    Vector3f ks;
    int      shininess;
    bool isRound; ...
```

However, no matter what shape I create, they both get **true** value. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code looks correct. The problem is somewhere outside of the code you posted.

Comment: is it possible both sphere and shape also define an isRound member?

Comment: Looks OK. Paste a code the compiles and runs?

Comment: How do you know what kind of shape you have? Found no virtual functions...

Comment: Thanks stijn! That was it, I had the isRound bool in the plane.h and sphere.h files as well. Deleting them solved the problem!

Comment: Just for future reference, it's not a good idea to have `isRound` as a non-const public member variable-- you know, the kind of thing that *anyone* can change.

Comment: Thanks Beta, I'll take it in mind!